# Передача JDBC connection для работы другому объекту

Tags: java, jdbc

Для работы другого объекта нужен коннект по JDBC. Чтобы снова его не открывать, хотелось бы передать его аргументом другому объекту. Не получается реализовать его.
в Первом объекте создается коннект. worker возвращает готовый connection:

```
DBWorker worker = new DBWorker();
```

Для работы в другом объекте, как его нужно передать?

```
Search search = new Search();
search.search(DBWoker connetion);
```

Но это не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DBWorker worker = new DBWorker();

...

Search search = new Search();
search.search(worker);
```